# Cocompletion with respect to a given class of diagrams

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

Let $C$ be a small category. If we want to form the free cocompletion of $C$ with respect to a class of diagrams with given shapes, it seems like we look at the full subcategory of $[C^{op},Set]$ spanned by presheaves that can be written as a colimit of a diagram of representables of the given shape. For example, the colimit completion of $C$ with respect to diagrams of discrete shapes is the subcategory of $[C^{op},Set]$ spanned by coproducts of representable presheaves.

Is there a reference where this is formally stated? (I'd like to cite this fact if possible)

Comment: A nice review is [Kelly and Shmitt](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501383), see Prop 3.6. They refer back to [Kelly's book](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/10/tr10abs.html) Thm 5.35, but in the unenriched case I'm not sure what an original reference would be. For particular classes of colimits, like all $\kappa$-small colimits or all $\kappa$-filtered colimits, this might be in SGA 4...

Comment: Kelly's book is probably a fine reference.  Note that the theorem is slightly different from what you claimed: in general you have to close up the representables under the appropriate kind of colimits, i.e. take the smallest subcategory closed under such colimits and containing the representables.  In general this is bigger than the category of such colimits of representables; you might have to iterate your colimits (perhaps transfinitely).

Comment: @MikeShulman For clarification: When you say "...subcategory closed under such colimits" do you mean ...subcategory closed under such colimits of representables?"

Comment: @KarthikYegnesh No, I don't.  A subcategory D of a category C is closed under X-colimits if for any any diagram F:X->D, the colimit in C of F actually lies in D.  The point is that the subcategory of objects that are X-colimits of representables may not be so closed: the X-colimit of a diagram of X-colimits of representables may not be itself a single X-colimit of representables.  (Though it is in some cases, such as coproducts.)